# How do I calculate what percentage of my portfolio is large-, mid- or small- cap?

Tags: india, rebalancing, market-capitalization, small-cap-stocks

I live in India, I've invested in some equity mutual funds (that invest in the domestic market). Each of them has some money in mid-cap stocks and some in large-cap. In fact, one of my funds was primarily mid-cap when I started investing, but now has a substantial large cap component.

Keep in mind that there aren't consistent definitions of where the boundaries lie. So I'll go with the one [BSE](http://www.bseindia.com/indices/DispIndex.aspx?iname=MIDCAP&index_Code=59&page=1C0FE704-0697-44D4-A408-3DB1C75AD930) uses:

> Eligible universe shall comprise of companies aggregating 98.5% of
>   average market capitalization. This list shall be categorised under
>   large-cap, mid-cap and small-cap segment based on 80%-15%-5% market
>   capitalization coverage respectively.

Given all this, how do I find out what percentage of my money is in large-, medium- or small-caps? The reason I ask is that if I find that more than 80% of my corpus is large-cap, I'll make further investments in mid-cap. Conversely, if I find that less than 80% of my corpus is large-cap, I'll make further investments in large-cap.

I want to rebalance my portfolio to not have a bias towards or against large-cap. I can do that only if I know what percentage of my portfolio is large-cap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All mutual funds disclose their investments, funds are large cap only or midcsp etc. So it depends on what funds you choose.

Comment: It's not true that funds invest only in large-cap or mid-cap. For example, the ICICI Value Discovery Fund straddles both. Even a primarily large-cap fund usually has some mid-cap investments.

Comment: Yes. There are mixed cap and multi cap funds. There offer different benefits, and your objective is not met by buying these funds.

Comment: My goal is just to determine, given a fund, what percentage of its assets are in large cap as defined by BSE above.

Comment: Every fund declare the investment periodically. You can take it from there.

Comment: By manually counting each stock and its percentage in the fund, and checking against the BSE list of large-, mid- or small-cap funds?

Comment: Yes. You are looking at buying a mixed fund and this is the only way

Comment: I'm actually not looking at buying anything. I just want to know how much of my existing investment is in large caps vs mid vs small.

Answer (score 2):

The portfolio manager at Value Research Online does this very nicely. It tracks the underlying holdings of each fund, yielding correct calculations for funds that invest across the board. Take a look at the screenshot from my account: [image: The analysis view of the Value Research Portfolio Manager]

If you have direct equity holdings (e.g., not through a mutual fund), that too gets integrated. Per stock details are also visible.

Comment: Thanks, Vivek. The problem is that different people use different definitions of large- vs mid cap, so I want to use the definition the BSE uses, as I wrote in my question. Do you know if there's any tool that tells me what percentage of my portfolio is large-cap according to that definition?

Comment: I didn't know there was an official definition. Is it given somewhere on the BSE website?

Comment: It's linked from the question.

Comment: Funds don't follow the BSE definition, nor are they obliged to. Also, most of them have language that has escape clauses. Examples: Birla Mid Cap fund's official document says 'Upto 65%-100% in equity and equity related instruments of Companies with a market capitalization between Rs.150 crores to Rs.1,500 crores.' HDFC Midcap Opport says 'portfolio that is substantially constituted of equity and equity related securities of mid- and small-cap companies.' Each one does its own thing. Best bet is a 3rd party tool like above that at least standardises and makes them comparable.

Comment: I know that the percentage can vary over time. I'm just looking for a point-in-time snapshot. I also know that funds don't use the BSE definition, but I want to. And that's because I do not want to be either overweight or underweight large caps. If large caps are 80% of the market as BSE defines them, then I want to put 80% of my equity money in large caps. This works only if I use the BSE definition.

Comment: Interesting. I've never come across a publicly available tool that does this. You'll likely have to do it the hard way. Since a fund calling itself mid-cap will have small-caps and large-caps, it will involve tracking their underlying portfolios on a monthly basis. But adjusting your portfolio to match the BSE's percentage will probably mean a lot of transactions and tax outgo. I mean if a fund shifts a bit out of mid-cap and buys large cap, you'll have to do some matching transactions to adjust. What will be the benefit of such activity, I wonder.

Comment: I won't be selling anything. I'll just make subsequent investments in a way that gets me closer to my target.